# How accurate to the comics is the Iron spider suit from Infinity War?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, comic-adaptation

In the **Avengers: Infinity War**, Peter Parker gets the new *Iron spider* suit from Tony Stark. How accurate is it with the comics? The functionality of the suit as well as the background such as who made it, what's the story behind it etc.

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Iron_Spider_Armor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though, MCU's spider armor is not exactly the same as Iron Spider Armor from comics, but it has almost every feature that has including extendable spider arms. The only difference is the color scheme. While the armor in comics has red and gold like Iron Man armor, MCU one has classic red and blue.

From [Comicbooks](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/06/17/avengers-infinity-war-iron-spider-comics-accurate/),

> While the MCU Iron Spider kept much of the functionality that the Iron Spider had in the comics, including the extendable spider arms, it kept Spider-Man’s classic red and blue coloring instead of being red and gold like an Iron Man armor.

Besides this, this suit was designed by Iron Man in both comic and MCU, Peter gets the suit while getting into Ebony's ship in Infinity War. While in [the comics](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_529), Iron Man calls him to the lab and shows the new suit.

> Peter awakens next to Mary Jane, hearing a voice. He and Mary Jane see that its Tony Stark's voice coming from the eagle statue in their room. Through the speaker he tells Peter that he wants to see him in the lab. **Tony reveals to Peter that he's making the final slight modifications to his new uniform, considering Peter's old one was "just cloth". Stark elaborates on some of these enhancements including mesh webbing that allows for gliding, bullet-proof & heat resistant Kevlar and an emergency scanner.**